We couldn't create a new partition or locate existing one error, while trying to solve install operating system error, On windows 10
I got a new hard drive and was prompted to download new operating system, created a bootable drive on my other pc using windows creation media, plugged it on my pc with new hard drive and while going through the setup I keep getting the we couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one even after trying to create one on command prompt. Disk part.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Where is the new HDD? There may specific slots for the boot drive. 2. Start with the new HDD with no partitions, i.e., all free space. 3. Boot  from USB, e.g., Live Ubuntu or Hiren's BootCD USB, and use any disk management tool to see that the new drive is visible, i.e., working.


The drive that I see in the screenshot already has 465 GB of System Partition. Is this your new drive? You can not install Windows 10 on a System Partition. You need an NTFS formatted Primary Partition with enough free space or better an Unpartitioned Space. There are some more criteria's but this is one key requirement. If this is your new drive, I suggest you check why it already contains that partition. If not relevant, just Delete it and create an Unpartitioned Space.
